# MongoDB : Query with $where and space

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to use `$where` in a mongoDB query like following :

```
$where:"this.extracted_service.DATA.MYKEY WITHSPACE.length >1"})
```

The problem is one of the key has a space in it so It won't work like that.

Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace that with

```
$where:"this.extracted_service.DATA['MYKEY WITHSPACE'].length >1"
```

Comment: Nice that's it, just one more thing. Supposing `['MYKEY WITHSPACE']` is an array how can I access the first item since `.0` or `[0]` doesn't work ?

Comment: @Matthieu Riegler, `this.extracted_service.DATA['MYKEY WITHSPACE'][0]` is able to get the first element.

Comment: Humm you're right, i must have tried something very alike not exactly that. !